# Android MediaCodec Time Scaling

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm attempting to adjust the speed of a video (either slower or faster) using MediaCodec.  I'm able to user this for doing real-time filtering by decoding - filtering - encoding.  However, I'm having difficulty adjusting the rate at which the decoding / encoding is done as well as adjusting timestamps to:
1) duplicate frames to be sent to encoder
2) drop frames from decoder going to encoder

To end with a final 30fps video that has adjusted duration and perceived speed.

I've looked at this link:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java

How can I pause/resume decoding / encoding to accommodate these needs?
Is there an alternative way to do this with MediaCodec?

Thanks!

Comment: You can change the playback speed by altering the presentation time stamps for each frame.  This works fine for making the video run more slowly -- no need to double frames -- but I'm not sure how far you can take this when speeding the video up.  Might depend on the player.  In any case, this is done in the MPEG file structure, and does not require re-encoding the video, so it would be much faster and higher quality.  If you need some parts to run at a different speed than others, the player would need to support variable-frame-rate video.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  We want the final video to remain at the original fps such as 30 fps.  This ensures the video will play back fine on any device or player.  On iOS, there is a straight forward "scaleTimeRange:forDuration:" API that does this.  Looking for something similar to that.

Comment: In that case you're probably on the right track.  If you're just doing video then the simpler http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest should have what you need.  There isn't really a "pause / resume" because you're not working in real time; you submit the frames with whatever time stamps you want, as quickly or as slowly as you want.  Double or drop as needed.